# Bloomberg real-time data with lot sizes

Tags: trading, bloomberg, stockquotes

I am trying to download real-time trading data from Bloomberg using the api.

So far I can get bid / ask / last prices successfully but in some exchanges (like canada) quote sizes are in lots.

I can query the lots sizes of course with reference data api and write them for every security in the database or something like that but to convert the size for every quote tick is very "expensive" conversion since they come every second and maybe more often.

So is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Why don't query it once and store the information? Not sure I understand your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to multiply each value by lot size?  As long as the lot size is constant each quote is comparable and any computation can be implemented using the exchange values.  Any results scaled in a presentation layer if necessary.